# NodeJS How to get Data in server, sent from jquery ajax call via POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post

My client is making an ajax call

```
{{


        function callNode(){

        console.log("I am called");
        var data = {"emailId":"gopal@gmail.com"};



        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
           /* data: {
                blob: {wob:"1",job:"2", ar:[1,2,{a:'b'}]}
            },*/
            contentType: "application/javascript",
            //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType:'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/notification',                      
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('success');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                               
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log("some error in fetching the notifications");
             }

        });
    }
}}
```

I am able to get this request in my app.js but not able to get the data that I am passing
I tried to search but nothing is working

```
{{

      app.post('/notification', function(req, res) {
      JSON.stringify(req.params);


      /*
       var body;
       req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        console.log("Received body data:");       
         body += chunk;
      });

       // the end event tells you that you have entire body
      /*req.on('end', function () {
       try {
      var data = JSON.parse(body);
       colnosole.log(data);

    } catch (er) {
      // uh oh!  bad json!
      res.statusCode = 400;
      return res.end('error: ' + er.message);
    }

  }
   */


}}
```

Thing is its not coming inside any events of request and response(as I have seen many people using this to fetch the data.

Help me to know whats wrong here its first time ajax on node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you sending data as json the contentType needs to be changed with respect to that so the ajax call should be:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
       /* data: {
            blob: {wob:"1",job:"2", ar:[1,2,{a:'b'}]}
        },*/
        contentType: "application/json",
        //contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType:'json',
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/notification',                      
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                               
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("some error in fetching the notifications");
         }

    });
```

Over here you can see the contentType changed to application/json.

At the server end you need to check the request.body in order to get the data and not request.params.

Comment: It Worked Thanks V31. Only the changes mentioned by u are required to make it run :)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use body-parser middleware(https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and you need to declare which badyParser to use

- app.use(bodyParser.json()) or
- app.use(bodyParser.raw()) or
- app.use(bodyParser.text()) or
- app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())

  inside your main js file. Then req.body object will contain your json/text/raw/urlencoded data.

Answer (score 1):

[req.params](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params) doesn't do what you think it does.

```
app.get('/:route', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.route);
});
```

Visiting `/test` would populate `req.params.route` with `test`.

You're looking for `req.body`, which can only be used with the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware.